# Obtener todos los componentes de un div mediante Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un DIV lleno de varios Checkbox, como puedo obtener y recorrer todos esos Checkbox mediante un ciclo.

Estoy tratando de hacer una ventana que me permita quitar/asignar roles de usuarios y las validaciones la estoy haciendo por Javascript.

Algo así cómo:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        if($("#" + i).prop('checked')){
            alert(' ACTIVAR ROL ');
        }else{
            alert(' DESACTIVAR ROL ');
        }
    }
```

Pero sin el for que 1 a 10 porque la cantidad de los roles puede variar segun el usuario.

Comment: Puedes poner una clase común y recorrer todos los elementos con esa clase con each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es similar a otra respuesta pero agregando el identificador del DIV, si el id del div fuera "contenedor", la función quedaría:

```
function myFunction(){
  $("#contenedor > input[type=\"checkbox\"]").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      alert('Activar ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    } else{
      alert('Desactivar ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
}
```

De lo contrario manteniendo tu ejemplo con los input check con nombre (id=1,id=2, etc..) y el for podría quedar así:

```
function myFunction(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= $("#contenedor > input[type=\"checkbox\"]").length; i++){
    if($("#" + i).prop('checked')){
      alert('Activar ' + $("#" + i).attr('id'));
    }else{
      alert('Desactivar ' + $("#" + i).attr('id'));
    }
}
```

Ambas probadas con jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: Me sirvió la primera, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la función  each para recorrer los inputs
la funcion is(":checked") para verificar si estan marcados

ejemplo:

```
 $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").each(function(){
         if($(this).is(":checked"));
    {
     alert(' ACTIVAR ROL ');
    }
    else{
     alert(' DESACTIVAR ROL');
    }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Poner una clase a todos los Checkbox y luego usar la función **each**:

```
$("#myDiv .ckecks").each(function(){

   //Hacer algo con cada checkbox
   //la palabra reservada 'this' representa el actual checkboxs del ciclo.

});
```

Espero sea de utilidad.